# Formatting Output of an Array

Tags: powershell

I've encountered a situation that I cannot seem to find a solution to.  I am scraping a website using `Invoke-WebRequest` and when I look at my output from my array, several of the properties are `System.Object`s.  I need to find a way to have them be strings so that when I `Export-Csv` I can actually see the values.  Here is my code:

```
$params = @{api_id='';api_key='';page_size='100';site_id=''}
$stats = Invoke-WebRequest https://my.incapsula.com/api/visits/v1 -Method Post -Body $params  
$s = $stats
$s = $s | ConvertFrom-Json
$s = $s.visits
```

Here are what my results look like:

[image: Output from $s | FT]

Comment: This [post by Boe Prox](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/01/24/avoiding-system-object-or-similar-output-when-using-export-csv/) may be useful. Note: the script center link at the bottom is broken the script can be found on [his GitHub](https://github.com/proxb/PowerShell_Scripts)

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I read that article earlier already.  I actually figured out how to fix this.  I was on the right track on previous attempts.  I created a new object and for the properties that were system objects I used a ($_ | select -expandproperty 'propertyname').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create a new custom object and use the following syntax on the properties that were an object themselves:

`($_ | select -expandproperty 'propertyname')`